# Stop on error in PL/SQL developer or Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sql-developer, plsql-developer

At this time I am using TOAD to apply SQL*Plus scripts and there is an option to stop on the first error. After it I can fix the script and apply the remaining part.

Due to license issues we can't use TOAD anymore and we have a choice between Oracle SQL Developer or PL/SQL Developer. Is it possible to set such behaviour there?

For example, Aqua Data Studio just shows all errors at the end of execution, but it doesn't stop on them. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

When you process a script in SQL Developer using the "Run Script" button (not the "Run Statement" button), it uses SQL*Plus internally to execute your script.  Therefore using a SQL*Plus control setting which stops processing on errors should work. Try adding to the top of your script line like this:

```
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT FAILURE
```

Comment: Adding a little bit of explanation on this answer would provide some helpful context.

Comment: Added explanation/context.